# Visual Basic - Saving and loading a number with one digit or more to and from a .txt file

Tags: visual-studio

For my assignment I am making a ball game in visual basic where the player gets points for hitting the ball. I am having an issue with saving and loading a number/the highest score to a .txt file. So far, I have managed to save the name of the player and the high score to a .txt file, however it only saves/loads numbers from 0-9 and doesn't allow 2+ digit numbers. Thanks in advance. Below is the code I have:

**To save to text file**

```
   Dim FileNum As Integer

  'if the player's score (lblpoints) is greater than the high score (lblhighscore)

   If lblpoints.Text > lblhighscore.Text Then
        lblnewhigh.Visible = True
        lblhighscore.Text = lblpoints.Text
        lblbestname.Text = lblplyrname.Text

        'to save highscore to txt file

        FileNum = FreeFile()
        FileOpen(FileNum, "score.txt", OpenMode.Output)
        PrintLine(FileNum, lblbestname.Text)
        PrintLine(FileNum, lblhighscore.Text)
        FileClose(FileNum)

    End If
```

**To load from text file**

```
Dim FileNum As Integer

    'to fetch the highscore from txt file
    FileNum = FreeFile()
    FileOpen(FileNum, "score.txt", OpenMode.Input)
    lblbestname.Text = LineInput(FileNum)
    lblhighscore.Text = LineInput(FileNum)
    FileClose(FileNum)
```

Comment: So where is it going wrong save or load? Open the file up in notepad see what's being saved. If It's wrong edit it in notepad, then, load it with your code see if that works. Isolate the problem.

Comment: and why aren't you using .net to do this. Is that part of the rules?

Comment: I think it is going wrong in the save. I played it and I used the name 'eddie', which was saved on the first line of the .txt file and I got a score of '11', which it saved the number '9' on the second line of the text file. I then went into the text file and changed the number '9' to '11' and the number '11' loaded. However, when I beat the score of 11 it went back to 9 again.

Comment: I have to use visual basic for the project

Comment: Just use the debugger to see this go wrong.  "11" is less than "9" since "1" is alphabetically sorted before "9".  So your If() statement body isn't entered and you don't save the file.  Compare numbers, not strings.

Comment: It is now only saving numbers from 0-11, please help